# How to create a two dimension list from a single dimension list by adding a new element?

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a list with the format:

```
flist = [1, 2, 4, 5, 418, 711, 736, 1389, 1478, 1582...]
```

I have the code to create a dictionary with content per every element in the list above "flist":

```
test = " "
for x in (range(len(d[13]))):
    test += (d[13][x])
d[13] = test
```

for example, the content of the dictionary of the element "13" is:

```
d[13]
'  22\n\nLEARNING ON A GENERAL NETWORK\n\nAmir F. Atiya
```

Now, I want to create a two dimensional list, with:
1. Every element of the list "flist"
2. Content of the dictionary of that particular element

To have at the end:

```
final = [1, "content from Dictionary for this element"],[2, "content from Dictionary for this element"],[4, "content from Dictionary for this element"],[],[]...
```

I have tried:

```
final = []
for x in range(len(flist)):
    flist[x].append(d[13])
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'append'
```

but it aint working. Any hint will be appreciated!

And the result should be in dataframe pandas format:
Column1: element of the list in flist
Column2. Content of that element in the dictionary

Comment: `flist[0]` is not a list. It is just an integer which doesn't have `append` attribute.

Comment: You can use list comprehension `[[e, d[13]] for e in flist]`

Comment: `flist` is not a list...?

Comment: What do you mean by "Content of the dictionary of that particular element"? Should it be `d[flist[x]]` instead of `d[13]` every time?

Comment: I would personally have a list of dictionaries

Comment: the elements in "flist" are IDs, the same ID return content in the dictionary, i.e. in flist we find the "13", and if we take this ID and put it in the dictionary d[13], it will return text.
So I want to get basically at the end a list with ["ID", "text"], for all the IDs in flist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the list comprehension

```
final = [[e, d[e]] for e in flist]
```